# One Page Website - links to different sections using 'fake' pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

For a school assignment I have to design a website. I wish to create a one page website, however, we are required to link to different pages, i.e. we need a `contact.html` and we need to link to it. Not sure if its relevant but I would also like the page to smooth scroll to navigation to the required section

To get around this I thought I could change the location of the link when clicked to instead be an anchor on the page - but I got stuck. Below is the code I have so far come up with.

Below is the navigation section of the website's html:

```
<nav>
    <a href="index.html"><img alt="Logo" src="logo.svg" /></a> 
    <a href="menu.html">Menu</a>
    <a href="chef.html">Chef</a>
    <a href="location.html">Location</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Javascript with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
        $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
            var target = $(this).attr("href");
            target = target.substr(0, myString.length-5);
            //console.log(target);
            alert(target);
               if (target.length) {
                 $('html,body').animate({
                     scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

On the actual pages, i.e. `contact.html`, I intend to just redirect to the main page with the relevant anchor

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesmstone/neuyzg7p/1/)

Comment: If it is just for a school assignment, why not just make the 5 separate pages?

Comment: I also want to see if it's possible and I want to improve my javascript out of it

Comment: plus i like one page websites :D

Comment: I think `target = target.substr(0, myString.length-5);` should be `target = target.substr(0, target.length-5);`. Aside from that, what isn't working exactly? Can you provide a JSFiddle link?

Comment: So when you click on a link it takes you to the other html page so `contact.html` for example  not the anchor. I updated question with fiddle

Comment: This is not a real question. What are you asking? What you are trying to do with "fake pages" defies the point of an `href` - which means "hypertext reference".

Comment: If I do your homework for you, will I get your grade?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what your question is?  @Sparky -- You can have an A+ right now, if you want it :)

Comment: @DrewT The only reason I wish to do it that way is because its a requirement for my assignment - i guess calling it a "fake page" was poor choice of words by me - i just cant figure out a better way of describing it

Comment: @mattingly890, thanks!  OP, if you want to improve your JavaScript, then you'll need to learn more JavaScript, not have us do the work for you.

Comment: @Sparky sure -  I can pass on the grade for you!

Comment: @mattingly890 I have been trying to improve my JavaScript - the reason I posted the question was because I got stuck

Comment: If the assignment mandates that you link to different pages, then staying on the same page and scrolling around to anchors does not fit that requirement.  That's why others are asking you to be more clear about your question.

Comment: @Sparky yeah that makes sense - the requirement is more to do with linking to other pages so after speaking with my assessor about this he ( if its possible ) has allowed me to scroll to anchors so long as the page url changes so I was then going to use `history.pushState()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things :

- You should use `.on` instead of delegate :

`$("nav").on("click", "a", function ( evt ) {`

- You should also call `.preventDefault()` on your event to avoid getting redirected :

`evt.preventDefault();`

- In your fiddle you didn't import jQuery.
- Last, you're referencing a string with `target` but I think you're looking for a jQuery object :

`scrollTop: $("[name="+target+"]").offset().top`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neuyzg7p/4/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, that now causes a type error for the line  `scrollTop: target.offset().top` **Error:**
`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function general.js:174
(anonymous function) general.js:174
m.event.dispatch jquery-latest.min.js:3
r.handle`